# getElementsById - object related errors Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm working on a project to import specific real-estate listing information from realtor.com to excel. This code should visit a link to a listing in cell A1, and return the year the property was built in c1.  I am able to use the getElementsByClassName for certain searches, but with different listings, using (#).innerText becomes impractical. When I use getElementsById, I get either error 91 or error 424 - both of which refer to a missing object. I'm quite new to VBA and coding in general, so any advice and a little patience would be greatly appreciated!

Code I'm using now:

```
Sub GetYearBuilt()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim YearBuilt As Variant

'cell A1 contains a url to search
website = Range("A1")

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "Get", website, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response

'this line either causes error 91 - object variable or with block variable not set, or error 424 - object required
YearBuilt = html.getElementById("propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon_BuiltIn")(0).innerText
    
'return address to cell C1
Range("C1") = YearBuilt

End Sub
```

html code I'm trying to extract from:

```
<div class="propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon" id="propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon_BuiltIn">
      <div class="propertyDetailsSectionContentLabel">Built in</div>
      <div class="propertyDetailsSectionContentValue">1973</div>
</div>
```

While I could use the class "propertyDetailsSectionContentValue", there are far too many items with this class throughout the website.

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, not a collection.  Therefore it should be `YearBuilt = html.getElementById("propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon_BuiltIn").innerText`

Comment: Thanks for answering! unfortunately code is still returning an error 91 for that line.  Any other ideas?

Comment: try ```html.getElementById("propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon_BuiltIn").firstChild.innerText``` to get **Built in** or similarly you can use ```html.getElementById("propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon_BuiltIn").childNodes[0].innertext``` to get n-th child

Comment: It would suggest that an element with the specified id does not exist.  Maybe it's not included in your response?

Comment: Thank you for your input @Salman Malik, I'm trying the first.Child.innerText method and now the code is returning "error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method".  Is there a simple solution to this error that I am not seeing? I'm sorry but I have very little experience with this.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Try `html.getElementById("propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon_BuiltIn").getElementsbyClassName("propertyDetailsSectionContentValue")(0).innerText`

Comment: just to correct its not ```first.Child.innerText``` as you mentioned in your comment is it a typo or you did same in code? there's no dot (.) between first and Child

Comment: thank you for clarifying @Salman Malik, that was just an error in the comment, not in the code.

Comment: @TimWilliams, you, good sir, are a genius.  this works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: try it this way then ```html.querySelector("#propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon_BuiltIn").getElementsbyClassName("propertyDetailsSectionContentValue")(0).innerText```